# I want to split funds using PayPal Django using django-paypal

Tags: django, paypal, payout

I want to pay to the seller for his sold products How can I do this using in django please help. I'm looking into paypal payouts but is there any SDK? or anything that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you receive a full payment into your own account, you can later send money from that account in an automated way using Payouts. To be approved for Payouts, see the information at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts

You can use the Payouts-Python-SDK for your implementation.

Comment: can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Not unless your question is more specific, no

Comment: My question is simple how can I use django paypal to split money into the sellers. Suppose a buyer purchases something for $10 and there are 2 seller's products now I want to send their 70% from ten, or 80% which is $4 each seller. So I would give them $4 each and $2 is my fee on my platform.

Comment: You cannot. But as mentioned above if a whole transaction is received into your account, you can then later use Payouts to send part of the money to each seller, if your account has access to Payouts.